# save rtf source code and display rendered version

Tags: rtf

If I have the rtf source code-how can I save it so that it is properly rendered? As it is now-no matter how I save it (rtf, txt or doc) it ends up just as source code

Comment: How are you saving the RTF source? If you're doing this from, say, Notepad on Windows, it's possible it's adding a .txt extension to the file.

Comment: I had to change a word option, save it as .txt to have the rtf rendered.